# Get Ouput Of A Keras Model/Layer

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, keras, keras-layer

My Keras model is the [babi_rnn example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/babi_rnn.py) in the Keras repository.

I want to get the output (in words) of the model on a dataset.

I tried:

```
layer = model.layers[-1] # For the last layer
    f = K.function([model.get_input(train=False)], [layer.get_output(train=False)])
    print(f([x])[0])  # your activation tensor
```

but I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Sequential' object has no attribute 'get_input'
```

**How can I simply get the output of the model or layer upon being fed by an input?**

That is, I need

```
    # I supply the X list and want to get the Y list.

    Y = Model(X) # X and Y are both lists. Model.Layer[Index] can also be a use case.

    # The responses are the set of label probabilities for each word in the vocabulary.
```

So that I could do: `for x, y in zip(X,Y): print(x,y)` for seeing **what is the model actually doing**.

I think this should have been the simplest use case, but it looks troublesome to implement.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `model.predict` to get `Y` the `predict` function internally calls `_make_predict_function()` which does what you are trying to do.

But your model is trained to map certain type of input to certain type of output... so you need to take care of those while using the `predict` function and also interpreting the same. In this example this conversion is done in `vectorize_stories()` so try and understand what it is doing.

In this case to get the word predicted all you need to do after training the model is:

```
Y_pred = model.predict([tX, tXq])
for pred in Y_pred:
    print (vocab[pred.argmax()-1])
```

Note again `tX` is the vectorized test story `tXq` is the vectorized test query and `Y_pred` is your vectorized predicted answer by the model.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help. could you explain how to get output of any layer in general? I tried but am getting the error in the question. thanks.

Comment: For any layer you can use `model.layers[index].input` `model.layers[index].output` to get the input and output of the layer. Also for sequential models you can use `model.input` `model.output` for the input and output of the whole model.